# how to sumbit multiple values in same form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on inviting new users. In the UI am using J query to add text boxes to allow the user to enter many names and corresponding email-ids. On submit I just want to access all the name and emails( multiple values) in my controller. Now I just need a help. Is there a way to create a hash of values with corresponding name and eamil some what like this. {"name1" => "eamil1","name2" => "eamil2" } ...

Pls help me out in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'fields_for' tag and pass a name followed by [] and a form built as shown below will send an array of hash values.

```
<%= fields_for :"names[]", User.new do |builder| %>
    <%=builder.text_field :name%>
    <%=builder.text_field :name%>
    <%=builder.text_field :name%>
    <%=builder.submit%> 
<% end %>
```

On submitting the form generated by the above code, the params hash will contain names= [ {"name"=> "..."}, {"name" => "..."}, {"name" => "..."}]

Answer (score 0):

With you Javascript code, you should generate some HTML input like:

```
<input type="text" name="invited_persons[0][name]" />
<input type="email" name="invited_persons[0][email]" />

<input type="text" name="invited_persons[1][name]" />
<input type="email" name="invited_persons[1][email]" />
```

Thanks to the numbers used as scope, the generated `params` will be like:

```
{
  'invited_persons' => {
    '0' => {
      'name' => 'foo',
      'email' => 'foo@foo.foo'
    },
    '1' => {
      'name' => 'bar',
      'email' => 'bar@bar.bar'
    }
  }
}
```